# SQL database Connection does not Work Properly

Tags: c#, windows

Here i put some code... this code related to login system. here i have some problem.... when i enter right User id and Password or even Wrong User ID and Password both are authorized  and display message Login successfully.......how can be this... i don't understand why SQLConnection give authorization to Unknown user which are not in database....

See the Code....

```
string SQlcons = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True"


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String UN = txtUsername.Text;
        String PW = txtPassword.Text;
        string loginstr = "SELECT * FROM Login Where UserName = '" + UN + "' and Password = '" + PW + "'";

        SQLconn = new SqlConnection(SQLcons);
        SQLconn.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(loginstr, SQLconn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + txtUsername.Text);
            Records rcd = new Records();
            this.Hide();
            rcd.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Correct Password and ID :(");
            txtUsername.Text = "";
            txtPassword.Text = "";
        }
        SQLconn.Close();
    }
```

Plz... Give the solution and Suggestion to me..

Comment: lots of things.. First you are executing your query but not doing anything from the returned value, second do not concatenate string to form query, you are open to SQL Injection, Also look into `Command.ExecuteScalar` since you are only interested if results are returned or not.

Comment: Can you hone in a bit on your issue, is it simply not connecting to your database or an issue with your query to the database?

Comment: To elaborate on what Habib said, try using the password `'; Drop table Login; --` and see what happens.

Comment: @Greg yes, i think database not connect with my application when i try to run it, but even don't display any error at debugging....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(result == 0)
{
   //wrong login info,
} else {
   MessageBox.Show("Login Success");
}
```

ExecuteScalar() function returns the row count with given SQL String. In your case, you should check the returned integer value from ExecuteScalar(). If result is 0, user entered wrong login info. If result is 1, user entered right information.

Comment: Just to clarify, [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the first column of the first row of the query.  Your code example is still calling the incorrect function.